# If a matrix is symmetric then, is similar matrix symmetric also?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices, projection-matrices

A question regarding real similar matrices.

I know if $A\sim B$ then $A=P BP^{-1}$.

But if  $A^T=A\geq0$, should be said that  $B$ is symmetric and $P=P^{-T}$,
or can I have another choice?

Comment: Reconsider the particular case when $A$ is diagonal ( so symmetric) ... then $B=P^{-1}DP$ .. simply not only symmetric matrices are diagonalizable..

Answer (score 5):

No.  Try some examples: take a random symmetric $A$ and a random invertible $P$.

Comment: Dear Israel, 
Thanks for the comment. How can I proof it?

Comment: By counterexample. Take a random symmetric matrix $A$ and a random invertible $P$, and you probably have a counterexample on your first try (at least if $P$ isn't orthogonal).

Answer (score 3):

For a simple example, check at https://www.wolframalpha.com

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
$$

{{1,1},{1,0}}*{{1,0},{0,2}}*inverse{{1,1},{1,0}}

(insert directly above text into wolphram textbox)

However
if your matrix $P$ were chosen as orthogonal i.e. $PP^T=I$
then  $A=PBP^T$ and $A^T=PB^TP^T$ what really gives $B=B^T$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice counterexample:
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1} \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1} \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&2\\1/2&1}
$$

Comment: Interesting example for similar non-invertible matrices...